# FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, react-context

I have created a Next.js application and am using Firebase authentication. I have used the useContext hook for managing user state across my application.
The code for the AuthContext is as follows:

**auth.js**

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { getAuth, onIdTokenChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    
    const auth = getAuth();
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        return(onIdTokenChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if(user) {
                setUser(user);
            } else {
                setUser(null);
            }
        }))
    },[]);

    return(<AuthContext.Provider value={{user}}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>);
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

However, I'm getting the following error in the **auth.js** file:
[image]

1. I am not able to understand how to fix it.
2. Also, I want to know if using useContext() hook is better for route protection as opposed to storing user session cookies in the browser and verifying it from there.

Edit:
I have configured Firebase in firebaseConfig.js. The code for it is as follows:

**firebaseConfig.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Comment: Read the docs about firebase [setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). You will need to obtain `firebaseConfig` and initialize your app with them with `const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`. And then you will need to pass this `app` object to the `const auth = getAuth(app);`

Comment: Where are you initialising Firebase? Can you share that code as well?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, I have updated my original question to show the config file as well.

Comment: @mukunda instead of using `getAuth()` everywhere, can you `import { auth } from "../path/to/firebaseConfig.js"` and use `auth` directly?

Comment: @SergeySosunov You were correct. I had actually initialized the **auth** in the firebaseConfig.js file (code shown in an edit to the original question). Importing it fixed the error. Thank you.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, I realized it later than sooner. I did it as you recommend and it fixed the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was just getting the same error, I managed to fix this by doing:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig{
...
}
```

**And adding these lines like that:**

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore();

export { auth, db };
```

Comment: Yes, this initializeApp() is required with the firebaseConfig

Answer (score 4):

Initialize app like Marcos Oliveira said, with error handling:

```
try
{
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);
} catch(error) {
    console.log('Error:', error)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still dealing with this issue, my solution was to re-order my imports in the App.js.

For some reason, the components I imported needed to be in a specific order. Otherwise, the same error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I did solve the problem by:
first I created a firebaseConfig.js file and put my configs and exported auth

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAzlY091r0Ihxxxxxx5F8",
  authDomain: "mealxxxxxc.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "mealxxxxxc",
  storageBucket: "meaxxxxxpot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "10xxxx00",
  appId: "1:1092909165400:web:532xxxxx32d",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

then in authContext.js, I imported auth from firebaseConfig.js

```js
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebaseConfig";
export const AuthenticationContext = createContext();
export const AuthenticationContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const onLogin = (email, password) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userData) => {
        setUser(userData.user);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log("userData", userData.user);
      })
      .catch((er) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(er.toString());
        console.log(er.message.toString());
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for me, that error came about when I had all my firebase configurations on separate page/file (**Firebase.js**) including the following:

```
// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

export const storage = getStorage(app);
```

So, the initial setup for Firebase was okay.

However, I also had a ***separate page/file*** (**App.js**) where I called `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)` as well as other built-in Firebase auth methods...

But, I forgot to import app from Firebase.js and that error popped up after I called `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

Once I did imported app, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the app object which is not getting initialized before the context provider render's

You should import the 'app' from firebaseConfig.js or whatever.js file your firebase configuration is in, into your Context file.

> Note: make sure you are exporting the app from the configuration file

```
import { app } from 'location/to/firebaseConfig.js';
```

and in useEffect check for the 'app' if it exists then run the firebase-specific functions afterward and also add the 'app' to the dependency array.

```
   useEffect(() => {
    if (app) {
        //enter firebase-specific code here

        // for example:
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        });
    }
}, [app]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide **app** inside the **getAuth()** function

**CreateUser File**

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"; 
import {app} from './FirebaseConfig';


export const auth = getAuth(app);

export const createFirebaseUser = (email,password) =>{

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    
    const user = userCredential.user;
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    
  });

}
```

**FireBaseConfig file**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";



const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBqUdRQh_bAmZBESqrKl7qD0Ux7XVt4lkA",
  authDomain: "blink-app-d514b.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "blink-app-d514b",
  storageBucket: "blink-app-d514b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "237006400468",
  appId: "1:237006400468:web:b53ff39ee4cf1943d6c441",
  measurementId: "G-Z46RLK173Q"
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem was simple, forgot to import the config file :)

inside `index.js` or other root file -

```
import "./lib/firebase";
```

and there is not need to import things from there

Answer (score -1):

you just need to export firebase conifgurations as app or any other type and re import it inside the page you are working on.
for me it was like this

```
   `import { getAuth,signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
   import { useState } from "react";
   import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
   function SignInPage(){
   const auth=getAuth();
   const SignIn=()=>{
   signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password)
   .then((userCredentials)=>{
   const user =userCredentials.user;
   console.log(user);
   alert("successfully loged a user")
   })
   .catch((error)=>{
   const errorCode=error.code;
   const errorMessage=error.message;
   alert(errorCode,errorMessage);
   });
   }
   const [email,setEmail]=useState("")
   const [password,setPassword]=useState("")
   return(
   <div className="main">
   <input type={"email"} placeholder="Email" onChange= 
   {(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
   <input type={"password"} placeholder="Password" onChange= 
   {(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
   <button onClick={()=>SignIn(email,password)}>Create Account</button>
   </div>
   )}
   export default SignInPage;`
```