# Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

Hello I'm new to react native and I want to send an verification email to the user's given email and authenticate it through firebase but I get this error

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being
> deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)

. Can I know why this error occurs and how to solve it.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getAuth, isSignInWithEmailLink, signInWithEmailLink } from "firebase/auth";
export default function ({ navigation }) {
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const actionCodeSettings = {
    // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
    // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
    url: navigation.navigate('Phone Verification'),
    // This must be true.
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOS: {
      bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
    },
    android: {
      packageName: 'com.example.android',
      installApp: true,
      minimumVersion: '12'
    },
    dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
  };
 
  const handleEmailAuth = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then(() => {
        // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
        // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
        // if they open the link on the same device.
        window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
      })
    }

  const handleVerifyEmail = () => {
    // Get the email from AsyncStorage
    const emailForSignIn = AsyncStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');

    if (auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href)) {
      auth.signInWithEmailLink(emailForSignIn, window.location.href)
      .then(() => {
        Alert.alert('Email verified', 'Your email has been successfully verified!');
        // Navigate to the next screen upon successful verification
        navigation.navigate('NextScreen');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert('Error', `There was an error verifying your email: ${error.message}`);
      });
    }
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email!").required("Email is required!"),
  });

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
    },
    
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
  });

  async function submit() {
    formik.validateForm();
    Object.keys(formik.values).forEach((value) => {
      formik.setFieldTouched(value);
    });
    if (!Object.keys(formik.touched).length) return;
    for (let error in formik.errors) if (error) return;
    const data = formik.values;
    setValid(true);
    console.log(data);
    if (valid) {
      handleEmailAuth();
    }
    // setValid(false)
    // navigation.navigate('Message', {
    //   type: 'fail',
    //   messageTitle: 'Please check the details and submit again :(',
    //   messageText: 'Something went wrong.',
    //   // goto: '',
    //   // goButtonText: 'Go to Dashboard',
    // });
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <Header back={true} />
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View style={styles.pageContent}>
            <Image
              source={require("../assets/emailVerify.png")}
              style={styles.vectorimage}
            />
            {/* <DatePicker/> */}

            <View style={styles.inputcont}>
              <TextInputBox
                inputlabel="Email"
                placeholder="Enter Email"
                type="email-address"
                name="email"
                onChangeText={formik.handleChange("email")}
                onBlur={() => formik.setFieldTouched("email", true, true)}
                value={formik.values.email}
                error={formik.errors.email}
                touched={formik.touched.email}
              />
      

              <Button
                title="Verify"
                color="filledSecondary"
                size="big"
                onPress={submit}
              />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.inputcont}></View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

this is my firebase.js in util folder
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'api key here',
  authDomain: 'freshlyy-437ac.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'freshlyy-437ac',
  storageBucket: 'freshlyy-437ac.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '940915596506',
  appId: '######app Id here',
};

// Initialize Firebase
const auth=getAuth(firebaseConfig)
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const FreshlyyImageStore = getStorage(app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please just take a look to this issue:
[FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999293/firebaseerror-firebase-need-to-provide-options-when-not-being-deployed-to-hos)

I would recommend to switch to react-native-firebase if you care about performance and especially cause it can contains native features you may need if you will use other firebase services in the future.

Also there is some errors in you code. You call the window object to get the local storage web API. You should use AsyncStorake or mmkv instead.