# How to use stripe payments in firestore without firebase.auth?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to use Stripe Payments in my node.js app, which sells products to users via whatsapp.

I installed the stripe extension: stripe/firestore-stripe-payments@0.3.3 and did what the documentation says:

```
const docRef = await db
  .collection('customers')
  .doc(currentUser.uid)
  .collection('checkout_sessions')
  .add({
    price: 'price_1GqIC8HYgolSxxxxxxxxx',
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  });
// Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
docRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
  const { error, url } = snap.data();
  if (error) {
    // Show an error to your customer and
    // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
    alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
  }
  if (url) {
    // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, let's redirect.
    window.location.assign(url);
  }
});
```

I get the following error in the cloud console:

`❗️[Error]: Checkout session creation failed for doc [maxxxxxxxxxA]: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.`

I found out that I need to use the userId from firebase Authentication, but since I run my service in functions (backend server), I have no client/user in auth.

Is there another way to create an (individual) stripe checkout link? Is there a way to use firebase Authentication without a client?

thank you in advance.

I tried using auth,

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;
```

but I got following error:`FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)`

I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74732162/21612440

and get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')`

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions run (in principle) without the context of a currently authenticated user. So `auth.currentUser` has little meaning in a Cloud Function, as each request may be coming from a different user.

But you can pass any UID you want into the Firestore database here `.doc(currentUser.uid)`. So if you can determine the relevant UID in some other (secure) way, you can pass that value and the Stripe extension will process it for *that* user.